# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Request header queries do not support projections, selections or sorting

Tags: java, android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am trying to read files from external storage of file, but when I try to convert filepath from content-uri, I get the exception on unsupported Operation on ContentResolver query:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Request header queries do not support projections, selections or sorting

I have never faced this exception before and this is running fine in my other app but I can't find what am I missing here.

1 things, if someone can point out that is fileProviders necessary for this operation?

Following is my code flow:

onActivityResult :

```
 List<Uri> uris = fileUtil.extractUriFromIntent(data);

        if (uris != null && !uris.isEmpty()) {
            String filePath = fileUtil.getPath(getActivity(), uris.get(0));
            prepareAttachment(filePath == null ? "" : filePath);
        }
```

and following are the lines for content Resolver query:

```
public  String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                           String[] selectionArgs) {

            Cursor cursor = null;
            final String column = "_data";
            final String[] projection = {
                    column
            };

            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I expect to get filePath for the file in content uri But query throughs above mentioned expection.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I think I implemented some other soltution for it. We revamped the application and everything was changed.

Comment: @Myzel394 If you can tell your exact problem. Maybe I can help.